# How can I dynamically change the appearance of a JSF command button?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have some Java code that decides what value gets placed in this JSF command button below. Several buttons are created and they either say "not available" or "available".

I need the "available" to keep appearing exactly as they are, but I'm wondering if there's a way to have the "not available" buttons that are created appear as simple text, since they aren't going to direct the user anywhere but I'm unsure of how to do it.

So far, I've tried using JSF's "render" feature to create the button only when the button should read "available" but since many buttons get created, it just ends up displaying nothing.

```
<h:column headerClass="columnHeader" footerClass="columnFooter" itemValue="0"><f:facet name="header">Fire Studies</f:facet>
        <h:commandButton id="btnSearch" value="#{SPP.fireStudyTitle}" action="#   {searchBean.doMagic(SPP.acronym)}" immediate="true" onchange="submit();" 
    style="font-weight:bold; font-size:small;"  onclick="javascript:cursor_wait()" class="buttonsFEIS" />&#160;&#160;
    </h:column>
```

Comment: Did you try using the "disabled" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the 'rendered' attribute ?

```
<ui:param name="showTheButton" value="#{ Some EL conditions }"></ui:param>
<h:commandButton rendered="#{showTheButton}" />
<h:outputText rendered="#{! showTheButton}" />
```

This way you can conditionally show completely different elements

Alternatively you can use the 'disabled' attribute as @danRod suggested

Comment: I think the OP just want to change button's style when it gets the message "not available", that's why I don't consider workaround with the `rendered` attribute

Comment: Sure you can use a combination of a varying styleClass and 'disabled' property. But what if you want more differentiation, like displaying text or a dead link instead of a button, or setting another actionLister? Having 2 facelets and have only one of them rendered each time, could be a more flexible choice in some cases.